# How do I fix my MBR after removing dual boot OS?

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, multi-boot, grub

I have a PC which I cannot boot into anymore. I really really don't want to reinstall the OS on it. (I don't want to lose the data and, besides, it's Christmas week.)

The PC has an SSD which had Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit installed. After a while I also installed Ubuntu, which automatically added GRUB to make dual booting easy.

Everything was good, until I decided I want to get rid of Ubuntu, so:

- I used the Windows Disk Management tool to delete the Ubuntu partition and extend the Windows one to occupy all the free space which remained. It worked perfectly.
- Now after restarting I get the error `GRUB error: no such partition` or something similar. I expected this, since the Ubuntu partition doesn't exist anymore.
- Like so many articles and pages I found online said: I went ahead and booted from the Windows 7 DVD (it was the exact same DVD I used when I installed the OS). When I booted, I saw I had 2 choices for my DVD drive: one with UEFI, the other with AHCI.
- I tried UEFI first. When going to "Repair my computer" I got some error message that said I should "use a DVD that is suited for my installed OS" or something along those lines.
- Restarted and booted again, but this time using the AHCI option.
- This time I got to the "Repair my computer" window and went directly to the Command Prompt.
- It took me a while to find that `bootrec.exe` was in `/Windows/System32`. I executed `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`. The message was "Operation completed succcessfully"
- Restarted.
- Still the exact same error from GRUB (which is weird because shouldn't the `bootrec` command get rid of it?)

I saw something weird, which I think is **extremely relevant**. From what I saw on some pages/tutorials, when you click on "Repair my computer" the tool should scan for Windows installations and show them in a list, like this:

[image: IMG:]

However, in my case, the list was **completely empty**, which is probably why `bootrec` didn't work. My best guess is that it's because my Windows is on an SSD, and it needs some sort of drivers to properly load/see it. I'm not 100% sure of this though.

I don't want to try 100 random things and completely break it, so what should I do? Has anyone been in this situation before and found a solution that really works?

If I'm right about needing drivers because of the SSD, where do I get them from and how do I load them?

Answer (score 2):

Boot using a Windows 7 installation disk, after the first screen where you select your keyboard layout, press SHIFT-F10.

It should open a command prompt with basic funcionality and some system recover utilities.

Type the commands:

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
```

This should be enough to get your system booting again. Do a normal reboot and see how it goes.